# Adding values from list into Attribute with UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I have a list of values of buildings total height and want to update the corresponding field in the shapefile.

fclass is my shapefile
totalh is the field which i want to update
totaheight is a list with height values for each building in the shapefile (same order)

This is what I am trying:

```
i = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fclass,"totalh") as updatecursor:

    for row in updatecursor:

        row[i] = total_height[i]
        updatecursor.UpdateRow(row)
        i = i+1
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/wspace2/bheights.py", line 45, in <module>
    updatecursor.UpdateRow(row)
AttributeError: 'da.UpdateCursor' object has no attribute 'UpdateRow'
```

Comment: `row[n]` refers to **column** 'n' in the row, so you're about to have a problem once you fix the capitalization.

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
updatecursor.UpdateRow(row)
```

to

```
updatecursor.updateRow(row)
```

The U is lowercase.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm

Also, check the following statement:

```
row[i] = total_height[i]
```

this should probably be

```
row[0] = total_height[i]
```

since you want to reference and update the first attribute in the shape file